# Dispersion / group velocity in tapered fiber

Tags: speed, dispersion, fiber-optics

dispersion in fibers are defined as:

$$D=-\frac{2 \pi c}{\lambda^2}\ddot{\beta}$$

where:

$$\ddot{\beta}=-\frac{1}{v_g^2}\frac{dv_g}{d\omega}$$

where $v_g$ is group velocity

Does the group velocity / dispersion change in a tapered fiber? If yes, how?

source of equations: [first](https://www.fiberoptics4sale.com/blogs/wave-optics/dispersion-in-single-mode-fibers), [second](https://www.scribd.com/document/323057636/Phase-Group-Vel-Dispersion)

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to enter mathematical 
expressions on Physics SE, as it is the site standard. Images of text or equations 
are very strongly discouraged.

Comment: equations are now in Mathjax

Comment: Well done! You’re a quick learner. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tapered fibers or nanofibers, the dispersion strongly changes with the diameter. It's basically because $\beta$ or the "effective index of a mode" $n_{eff}$ depend on the refractive index profile of the waveguide (source: [link](https://www.rp-photonics.com/effective_refractive_index.html)). A nice explanation of what happens with tapered fibers can be found in the book of L. Tong (ISBN: 978-3-642-03362-9) or maybe here [link](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/10/2/715/htm).